# Partial text sent when using SendKeys in Protractor

Tags: protractor

Inconsistently, the partial text is being sent when using `SendKeys` and causes a particular spec to fail. Below is the test that needs to happen for the other tests to past successfully

```js
    it('should select a template report', function() {
        reports.createTemplateBtn.click();
        reports.selectTemplate.click();
        browser.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys('Guest RSVP Status' + protractor.Key.ENTER);
        browser.sleep(1000);
        reports.startBtn.click();
    });
```

The test is clicking a field (Select Template) which then shows a drop-down to type in the type of template to be used. The issue is with sending 'Guest RSVP Status'. Inconsistently, only portions of the phrase will be sent and cause the rest to error out. Is there a better way to implement Send Keys and/or should sleeps be added? 1/5 times the full text is sent successfully.

Update: `slowType` errors out below. Sleep is not a function.

```js
function slowType(elm, keys, delay){
        var action = browser.actions().mouseMove(elm).click();
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            action = action.sendKeys(keys[i]).sleep(delay);
        }
        return action.perform();
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if protractor has a way to wait until the current element value is what you want it to be?

Comment: Could it be that there is a "slow" validation going on during the field modification? What if you try to [slowtype into the field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187514/simulate-slow-typing-in-protractor)?

Comment: @alecxe there is a validation occurring. With the recommendation, I am using the following but receiving a failure ``action.sendKeys(...)sleep is not a function``

Original post updated with code.

Comment: can you try `reports.selectTemplate.click().sendKeys('Guest RSVP Status' + protractor.Key.ENTER);`? Because it seems the element you click is the same element you want the text to be passed on.

Comment: @ErnstZwingli I've tried that but it is still inconsistently successful.

Comment: Ok. One important question: which part of the text isn't send? Always first 2-3 letters missing or always last few letters missing or random letters in between (like i.e. `RSPStus`)? Because it's most probably connected to page loading bwhavior and a UI-blocker element (loading...) ... so I'd like to figure out, when the loading action happens.

Comment: @ErnstZwingli the letters are inconsistent. It appears to be a timing issue with the lookup validation that we have. Some instances it sends all keys as expected, in others it only sends partial keys, different each time.

Comment: In that case someone skilled wirh 10-finger-keyboard writing can probably manually reproduce the issue. I'd suggest to file a bug, that the lookup validation shall only be triggered after i.e. 300 Milliseconds of no input (instead of permanently immediately). It would probably also reduce graffic to the backend. Alternatively you can try with Copy-Paste-Key combos, so you don't enter it key by key, but as paste object in once

Comment: One other thing I can provide as info is [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25740114/8683679) to improve the speed of SendKeys... however, it's a bit of a hackery. But honestly I see this more a problem of bad User Experience (and therefore a bug) than a Protractor issue.